# How to add an 'any' to a lambda function where features are arguments?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

Giving the following dataframe:

```
    name      both     one
1  'ABC AB'  'AA-BB'  
2  'AB NNN'  'AA-CC' 
3  'CCC MM'  'DD-BB'
4  'MM NNN'  'DD-CC'
```

I want to populate feature `one` with either the first or the second element of feature `both` based on the fact that the value from feature `name` includes or not `any` of the items of a certain list.

E.g. for the list above, if the value of `name` includes any of the items of `lst`, the value attributed to `one` should be the SECOND part of `both`, otherwise the FIRST part. Output should look like

```
lst = ["AB", "NNN"]

    name      both     one
1  'ABC AB'  'AA-BB'  'BB'  
2  'AB NNN'  'AA-CC'  'CC' 
3  'CCC MM'  'DD-BB'  'DD'
4  'MM NNN'  'DD-CC'  'CC'
```

I've tried both things below, but neither worked entirely.

The result of the `else` actually works as expect, but not what is `true` for the `if`.

```
df["one"] = df["both"].apply(lambda x: x.split("_")[1]
                                       if any(n in df["name"] for n in lst)
                                       else x.split("_")[0])
```

⬆️ This doesn't return an error but doesn't return any result for the matches of the `if` filter either.

```
df["one"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["both"].split("_")[1]
                               if any(n in x["name"] for n in lst)
                               else x["both"].split("_")[0])
```

⬆️ This returns a `KeyError: 'name'`

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

lst = {'AB', 'NNN'}
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['ABC AB', 'AB NNN', 'CCC MM', 'MM NNN'],
                   'both': ['AA-BB', 'AA-CC', 'DD-BB', 'DD-CC']})

df['one'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['both'].split('-')[1] if set(x['name'].split()).intersection(lst) else x['both'].split('-')[0], axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
     name   both one
0  ABC AB  AA-BB  BB
1  AB NNN  AA-CC  CC
2  CCC MM  DD-BB  DD
3  MM NNN  DD-CC  CC
```

(In your second attempt you have used underscores instead of hyphens and you have not specified the axis).

Comment: Thank you, @david-m. The underscores are a mistake in my question above only, thanks for spotting. Ref. the axis, do you think my second approach would work if I'd define the axis? And if so, where exactly?

Comment: Yes: `df["one"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["both"].split("-")[1] if any(n in x["name"] for n in lst) else x["both"].split("-")[0], axis=1)`